# C# label control not working properly

Tags: c#, label

When I run the following code, it populates the `label1` control one time.  Then the `label1` control does nothing else.  How do I get the `label1` control to change on the mouse enter events.  Please provide code examples.

```
    int currentXposition, currentYposition;
    const string positionLabel = "Current Position: ";

    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        var temp=Color.Transparent;    //Used to store the old color name of the panels before mouse events
        var colorName = Color.Red;      //Color used to highlight panel when mouse over
        int numBlocks = 8;             //Used to hold the number of blocks per row
        int blockSize=70;

        //Initialize new array of Panels  new
        string[,] Position = new string[8, 8];
        Panel[,] chessBoardPanels = new Panel[numBlocks, numBlocks];
        string Alphabet = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";
        string Numbers ="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
        string[] alphaStrings = Alphabet.Split(',');
        string[] numStrings=Numbers.Split(',');
        // b = sub[0];
        int FirstValue, SecondValue;

        //Store Position Values
        for (int firstValue = 0; firstValue < 8; ++firstValue)
        {
            FirstValue = Alphabet[firstValue];
            for (int SecValue = 0; SecValue < 8; ++SecValue)
            {
                SecondValue = Numbers[SecValue];
                Position[firstValue, SecValue] = alphaStrings[firstValue] + numStrings[SecValue];
            }
        }

        //Loop to create panels
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numBlocks; iRow++)
        {
            for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < numBlocks; iColumn++)
            {
                Panel p = new Panel();
                //set size
                p.Size = new Size(blockSize, blockSize);
                //set back colour
                p.BackColor = (iRow + (iColumn % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;
                //set location
                p.Location = new Point(blockSize *iRow+15, blockSize * iColumn+15);
                chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn] = p;
                chessBoardPanels[iRow,iColumn].MouseEnter += (s,e) =>
                {
                    currentXposition = iRow;
                    currentYposition = iColumn;

                    var oldColor = (s as Panel).BackColor;
                    (s as Panel).BackColor = colorName;
                    temp = oldColor;
                    label1.Text = Position[iRow, iColumn];
                };

                chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn].MouseLeave += (s, e) => {
                    (s as Panel).BackColor = temp;
                };
                groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What is your question ? "please provide..." isn't a question...

Comment: Please provide less C# and more english. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what is the GUI framework ? WinForms by the looks of it...

Comment: When I enter one of the panels  'chessBoardPanels[0,0] or chessBoardPanel [2,2] I would like the label1 control to change to the current chessboard position coordinates.  The grid actually is a 8 x 8 grid

Comment: You are using the varaibles `iRow` and `iColumn` in your event handler, but by the time the event handler is called your loops have ended, and the variables point outside the grid.

Comment: similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765036/why-wont-the-label-populate) he posted a few minutes ago

Comment: Thanks @iabbott, I voted to close. Please do not recreate questions just because you aren't getting responses you like

Comment: Ok, well when I don't get an answer that doesn't make the situation go away either

Comment: Maybe if I sit here and wait till next week someone might actually post a comment like the one Guffa posted which actually makes sense.  Like I said earlier, it doesn't matter to me whether I like the comments or not.  I'm trying to find some sort of solution to this problem instead of trying to play some sort of ego trip  Justin

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this only because I think it's important to show what happens when scope is confused.  The reason you're having your issue is the scope of your variables. Your label is changing `iRow * iColumn` times, but only during initial execution.  From then on, `iRow` and `iColumn` are fixed at their final values.

To achieve your desired end goal, it'd be easiest to create an extension of Panel:

```
public class ChessPanel : Panel {

     private const Color HighlightColor = Color.Red;


     public int iColumn { get; set; }
     public int iRow { get; set; }
     public Color PrimaryColor { get; set; }

     public ChessPanel() : base()
     {
        this.MouseEnter += (s,e) =>
                {
                    this.PrimaryColor = this.BackColor;
                    this.BackColor = HighlightColor;
                };

         this.MouseLeave += (s,e) => 
                {
                    this.BackColor = this.PrimaryColor;
                };
     }     

}
```

This will then allow you to reduce your code as follows:

```
int currentXposition, currentYposition;
const string positionLabel = "Current Position: ";

private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
    var temp=Color.Transparent;    //Used to store the old color name of the panels before mouse events
    var colorName = Color.Red;      //Color used to highlight panel when mouse over
    int numBlocks = 8;             //Used to hold the number of blocks per row
    int blockSize=70;

    //Initialize new array of Panels  new
    string[,] Position = new string[8, 8];
    ChessPanel[,] chessBoardPanels = new ChessPanel[numBlocks, numBlocks];
    string Alphabet = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";
    string Numbers ="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8";
    string[] alphaStrings = Alphabet.Split(',');
    string[] numStrings=Numbers.Split(',');
    int FirstValue, SecondValue;

    //Store Position Values --- no idea what this is supposed to do...
    for (int firstValue = 0; firstValue < 8; ++firstValue)
    {
        FirstValue = Alphabet[firstValue];
        for (int SecValue = 0; SecValue < 8; ++SecValue)
        {
            SecondValue = Numbers[SecValue];
            Position[firstValue, SecValue] = alphaStrings[firstValue] + numStrings[SecValue];
        }
    }

    //Loop to create panels
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numBlocks; iRow++)
    {
        for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < numBlocks; iColumn++)
        {
            ChessPanel p = new ChessPanel();
            //set size
            p.Size = new Size(blockSize, blockSize);
            //set back colour
            p.BackColor = (iRow + (iColumn % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;
            //set location
            p.Location = new Point(blockSize *iRow+15, blockSize * iColumn+15);

            p.MouseEnter += (s,e) =>
            {
                var cpSelf = s as ChessPanel;
                if (cpSelf != null)
                {
                    label1.Text = Position[cpSelf.iRow, cpSelf.iColumn];
                }
            };

            groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
            chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn] = p;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you're making use of many of those variables later on int the program, and looking at this kind of makes my head hurt, so I left most of it in place.

Delegates are a very powerful and useful utility, but they can cause confusion with variable scope.  Be very careful when using these, and make sure you treat them as functional units that execute later and can therefore only rely on the state of the program at execution of the block rather than at creation of the block.  If you notice, I kept the reference to the `Position` array simply to show that you can still access local variables within the scope of the delegate because it is technically still in scope.  Structurally, this could easily be moved into the ChessPanel class and referenced 100% locally.  This example should be  used as a caution as it can show how a "local" variable that many people assume are garbage-collected at end of function execution can hang around and eat up memory.

This code is untested and may have minor syntax errors.  Hopefully the spirit of the structure is understood.

Comment: Yes,  I understood what you had mentioned about the variable being outta scope.  This at least gives me a direction to go with it.  I appreciate the help with this.